# Counting multidimensional array rows and their respective elements?

Tags: php

I'm doing something that is perhaps too long and strange to explain, but basically I've mapped a string in a complex way into an array in a way to make them jumbled up. This is an example of how it would look:

```
field[26][25]='x';
field[24][23]='z';
field[28][29]='y';
```

Now that I've successfully jumbled up the string in exactly the way I wanted, I need to reconstruct the linear result.

So I need to take row 1 of the array, and loop through all the elements in this row to combine them into a string. Then do the same thing with row 2 and so on to create one massive linear string.

How do I count how many rows and elements in those rows I have? For the life of me I cant even begin to find how to do this for multid arrays.

Kind regards

Comment: `foreach` and `implode`

Comment: What exactly do you need? To count the items on each row or to join all the values in a certain order into a string? The two tasks are not necessarily related; you can join the values without counting them.

Answer (score 0):

@u_mulder's got a solid answer there. For the number of elements, you'd just say:

```
$total = 0;
foreach( $matrix as $row ) $total += count($row);
```

For the concatenation of elements, you'd just say:

```
$concat = '';
foreach( $matrix as $row ) $concat .= implode('', $row);
```

Bob's your uncle. But really, is there a valid use case for such a strange mashup?

Answer (score 0):

```
$field[26][25]='x';
$field[24][23]='z';
$field[28][29]='y';
$field_string = '';
array_walk_recursive ( $field , function($item, $key) use (&$field_string){
if(!is_array($item)){
    $field_string .= $item;
}
});
echo $field_string;
```

Honestly, this is a little confusing. I may need more info but let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can start with an empty string and use two nested `foreach` to iterate over lines and items on each line and append each item to the string:

```
$result = '';
foreach ($fields as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        $result .= $item;
    }
}
```

Or you can replace the entire inner `foreach` with `$result .= implode('', $row);`.

You can even replace the outer `foreach` with a call to [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) then [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the array produced by `array_map()` into a string:

```
$string = implode(
    '',
    array_map(
        function (array $items) {
            return implode('', $items);
        },
        $fields
    )
);
```